# Can I draw circle on AnchorPane in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I tried to make Othello. As the first step,I want to draw 4 stones on board when start button clicked. That code will be connected to Controller code.

```
public class Board {
@FXML AnchorPane gamePane; // game board

private final int EMPTY = -1;
private final int BLACK = 0;
private final int WHITE = 1;
private final int boardsize = 8;
private int board[][];

public Board() {
    board = new int[boardsize][boardsize];
    for(int i = 0; i < boardsize; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < boardsize; j++) {
            board[i][j] = -1; 
        }
    }
    drawBoard();
}

public void NewGameBoard() {
    board[3][3] = BLACK;
    board[3][4] = WHITE;
    board[4][3] = BLACK;
    board[4][4] = WHITE;

    drawBoard();
}

public void drawBoard() {
    for(int i = 0; i < boardsize; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < boardsize; j++) {
            if(board[i][j] == BLACK) {
                Circle stone = new Circle(470,445,45);
                // <--- draw Circle on gamePane
            }
            else if(board[i][j] == WHITE) {
                // <---draw Circle on gamePane
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is failed code. I wrote fxml code that shows unchangeable part but don't know how to draw Circle on javafx code.

Comment: “failed code” isn’t a description of a problem.  Did you try adding the Circle nodes to your gamePane?

Comment: Research `GridPane`.

Comment: Research how the `initialize` method is used in the controller class...